# "Fictious" Contact List Created

Tags: list

I created a fictious CONTACT LIST on Visual Studio, and I deployed to the server. So it is displayed at Quick Launch menu. 
Well, when I desactive that feature, it still remain displayed .. I wonder if it doesnt be hided of Quick Launch menu!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deactivating a feature does nothing, if you do not tell it to do something. Similarly as creating a list (or adding a list instance) in the feature, you will also have to write code to remove the list on deactivation (if that is what you need)